# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

Tags: python

```
name, Ll, eLL, Mg= np.loadtxt('data.txt', comments='#', unpack=True)
Ntrials= sum(1 for line in open('data.txt'))
```

The data file contains four columns with values under every column
[Data file info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPAi.png)

Does anyone know why I am getting that error?

Comment: I can't tell what's going on without seeing what's inside the file `data.txt`. Could you post the contents of that file?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: There isn't enough information to be certain of what is going on, but it seems like whatever is happening with that `np.loadtxt` it is not returning the array you are expecting. If you aren't receiving any errors then I suggest using a debugger to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I am not sure why you got that specific error. However, I am surprised that you did not have to specify the datatype for your data considering that one of the columns is a string.
The only time I have noticed that specific error is when the txt file is empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create 4 variables which are **name, Ll, eLL, Mg**, so make sure that you are getting 4 values from right hand side code.

```
np.loadtxt('data.txt', comments='#', unpack=True)
```

The above line must contain 4 values otherwise unpacking will not happen and ValueError will be thrown.

You can learn more about unpacking here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp

Comment: The documentation of `numpy.loadtxt()` says it returns a value for each column. So if the file has 4 column, there should be 4 values.

Comment: Your answer isn't very helpful. How is he supposed to "make sure" of that? He's not a numpy developer.

Comment: The best way to debug this is to print np.loadtxt() before unpacking it, We will get to know what exactly we have in bumpy.loadtxt(), Even I am not numpy developer. thanks.

Comment: The error message says "got 0". That means the result is an empty tuple, not very helpful in figuring out why.

Comment: that's why we need to make sure that we are getting 4 values. either the file is empty or issue with np.loadtxt() which we need to debug.

Comment: Your answer focuses on the wrong part. The question is: How do we get np.loadtxt to return the desired 4 values.

Comment: Cool bro. I did my best to help him. If you know the answer, Just go ahead and provide him instead of pointing someone.

Comment: I don't know the answer because we don't have enough information. The problem is probably with the input file.